# If "bash <file>" works, why is "source <file>" throwing an error?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
if :; then
    echo a
fi
```

If I run `bash /tmp/file`, `a` is echoed, but if I run `source /tmp/file`, I get:

```
bash: /tmp/test: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

The output:

```
knezi@holly tmp]$set -x; source /tmp/test; set +x
+ source /tmp/test
++ set -x
bash: /tmp/test: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file
+ set +x

knezi@holly tmp]$set -x; command source /tmp/test; set +x
+ set -x
+ command source /tmp/test
+ source /tmp/test
++ set -x
bash: /tmp/test: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file
+ set +x

knezi@holly tmp]$bash -c "source /tmp/test"
+ bash -c 'source /tmp/test'
++ :
++ echo a
a


knezi@holly tmp]$od -c /tmp/test
0000000   #   !   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h  \n   s   e   t    
0000020   -   x  \n   i   f       :   ;       t   h   e   n  \n  \t   e
0000040   c   h   o       a  \n   f   i  \n
0000051
```

Output of commands `shopt -p` and `set -o`: http://pastebin.com/bsqc8aru

Output of `set`: http://pastebin.com/S9KpqZAL

`declare -fp` produces nothing.

I thought that `source` does the same as `bash`, but instead of starting new session rather runs the code in the current one. Can anyone explain this error to me?

I run bash GNU bash, version 4.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu).

Comment: is there something non-unix character embedded on your code ?

Comment: No, this is the whole code. Newlines are 0a.

Comment: ended with `0a` ? what is that ?

Comment: @Rahul the hexadecimal code of the Unix linefeed character

Comment: Is the `$BASH_ENV` set?

Comment: I don't see how it could make any difference, but just in case, what happens if you run `. /tmp/test`? Do you get the same issue?

Comment: @roaima: $BASH_ENV is empty.

Comment: @terdon: . /tmp/test produces the same result.

Comment: Does it work in noninteractive mode: `bash -c 'source /tmp/test` ?

Comment: @PSkocik that is really weird. bash -c "source /tmp/test" works.

Comment: Ah-ha! Please add that it works with `bash -c` to your question. Then, show us the contents of your `~/.bashrc` file, there's probably something there that's screwing things up.

Comment: Can you post the output of `shopt -p; set -o; set` somewhere, possibly after filtering out your private stuff from it?

Comment: @PSkocik I added it. This should be the default values (As far as I remember, I did not change them.).

Comment: @knezi add `set` (or `declare -fp` ) too please (shopt -p and set -o print settings; set or (better) declare -fp print functions and variables).

Comment: @PSkocik `declare -fp` produces nothing, `declare` produces exactly the same output as `set` (checked with diff :)).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I can reproduce your behaviour if I alias `fi`:

```
$ alias fi=:
+ alias fi=:
$ . ./test
+ . ./test
++ set -x
bash: ./test: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

It works when you execute it but fails when you source it because aliases are not available in non-interactive shells (the type of shell that runs shell scripts). As explained in [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html):

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the
>   `expand_aliases` shell option is set using `shopt` (see [The Shopt
>   Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)).

However, when you `source` something, it is run in your current shell which, because it is interactive, has already loaded the aliases and therefore the `fi` alias is recognized and breaks the sourcing.

Comment: You are completely right. I have set: alias fi='find -type f | xargs grep -H '.

Comment: Get rid of that `alias` now!  :)

Comment: I am astounded that anybody managed to figure out such an obscure problem. Well done, sir.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I suspected that something was aliased (because of the interactive shell), `set` was ruled out by the output, and `alias if='foo "'` (a trailing open quote gave an error about the missing quote, and so the last option was aliasing `fi`.